# Problemas al instalar Grails

Tags: java, variables, grails

Les hago una consulta, yo me baje el OpenJava 7 y Grails 2.5.1, estoy trabajando sobre ubuntu.

Fui al archivo **/etc/environment** y agrege las variables:

JAVA_HOME="ubicacion de la carpeta de java"
GRAILS_HOME="ubicacion de la carpeta de grails"

y luego en el **PATH** agrege lo siguiente: **:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$GRAILS_HOME/bin**

Y por ultimo corri el comando **source /etc/environment** para que me lo actualice.

Si yo ejecuto el comando javac -version me dice: javac 1.7.0_95 (Que es la version que instale)

Pero si ejecuto **grails -version** me limpia la terminal y no hace nada.

Si ejecuto echo $JAVA_HOME o echo $GRAILS_HOME me da la ubicacion de las carpetas.

A alguno se le ocurre que puede llegar a ser?

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar para manejar las distintas versiones de grails / java https://sdkman.io/. Cuando grails queda colgado puede ser por muchas cosas, pero gralmente es por problema con java (version), dependencias o la db